# array whose values are the product of every other integer

Tags: java, arrays, multiplication

I was asked the following interview question over the phone:

```
Given an array of integers, produce an array whose values are the product of every other integer 

excluding the current index. 

Example: 

[4, 3, 2, 8] -> [3*2*8, 4*2*8, 4*3*8, 4*3*2] -> [48, 64, 96, 24]
```

and I gave the following answer

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ProductOfAnArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ProductOfAnArray
                    .calcArray(new int[] { 4, 3, 2, 8 })));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ProductOfAnArray
                    .calcArray(new int[] { 4, 0, 2, 8 })));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ProductOfAnArray
                    .calcArray(new int[] { 4, 0, 2, 0 })));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ProductOfAnArray
                    .calcArray(new int[] {})));
            System.out
                    .println(Arrays.toString(ProductOfAnArray
                            .calcArray(new int[] { 4, 3, 2, 8, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7,
                                    3, 2, 4 })));
            System.out
                    .println(Arrays.toString(ProductOfAnArray
                            .calcArray(new int[] { 4, 3, 2, 8, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7,
                                    3, 2, 4 })));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ProductOfAnArray
                    .calcArray(new int[] { 4432432, 23423423, 34234, 23423428,
                            4324243, 24232, 2342344, 64234234, 4324247,
                            4234233, 234422, 234244 })));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // debug exception here and log.
        }
    }

    /*
     * Problem: Given an array of integers, produce an array whose values are
     * the product of every other integer excluding the current index.
     * 
     * Assumptions. Input array cannot be modified. input is an integer array
     * "produce an array" - type not specified for output array
     * 
     * Logic explanation:
     * 
     * Assume we have array [a,b,c,d] Let multiple be multiple of each element
     * in array. Hence multiple = 0 if one of the element is 0; To produce the
     * output. Ans at i -> multiple divided by the value at i. if 2 numbers are
     * 0 then entire output will be 0 because atleast one 0 will be a multiple
     * if 1 number is 0 then every thing else will be 0 except that index whole
     * value is to be determined
     * 
     */
    public static BigInteger[] calcArray(final int[] inp) throws Exception {
        if (inp == null)
            throw new Exception("input is null");

        int cnt = 0;
        BigInteger multiple = new BigInteger("1");
        boolean foundZero = false;

        for (int i : inp) {
            if (i == 0) {
                cnt++;
                foundZero = true;
                if (cnt < 2)
                    continue;
                else
                    break;
            }
            multiple = multiple.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }

        BigInteger ans[] = new BigInteger[inp.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
            if (foundZero) {
                if (cnt < 2) {
                    ans[i] = (inp[i] == 0) ? multiple : new BigInteger("0");
                } else {
                    ans[i] = new BigInteger("0");
                }
            } else {
                ans[i] = multiple.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(inp[i]));
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }

}
```

But I was not selected. I would like to get feedback on my answer and see whats wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this the right forum for your question.  Try asking on codereview.SE

Comment: So many people applying for the same interview :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried the same way in the past. didnt selected :) .
I tried to captured the index of zero if any in first loop. and simply assigned the product to that index ( i used double array and default would be 0) - so you dont need to iterate again if one zero found.

And checked the product is infinity `Double.isInfinite` in the first loop, if yes break the loop - no point of find product for remaining ( assume input is large numbers with high volume)

```
public static double[] arrayProducts(int[] input) {
    int length = input.length;
    double product = 1;
    boolean zeroFound = false;
    int zeroIndex = 0;
    double[] output = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (input[i] == 0) {
            if (zeroFound) {
                throw new ProductArrayException(0, true, zeroIndex,
                        ZERO_FOUND_EXPECTION);
            }
            zeroFound = true;
            zeroIndex = i;
        } else {
            product = product * input[i];
            if (Double.isInfinite(product)) {
                throw new ProductArrayException(0, true, zeroIndex,
                        INFINITY_FOUND_EXPECTION);
            }
        }
    }

    if (zeroFound) {
        throw new ProductArrayException(product, false, zeroIndex,
                ZERO_FOUND_EXPECTION);
    } else {
        output = new double[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            output[i] = product / input[i];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be the solution the interviewer was after:

```
    int[] arr = new int[]{4,3,2,8};
    int[] newarr = new int[arr.length];

    int product = 1;
    for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        product = product * arr[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newarr[i] = product / arr[i];
        System.out.print(newarr[i] + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given integer array `arr[]`,

```
int[]   arr = { 4, 3, 2, 8 };
int[]   prod = new int[arr.length];

for (int i = 0;  i < arr.length;  i++)
{
    prod[i] = 1;
    for (int j = 0;  j < arr.length;  j++)
        if (j != i)    // Exclude element at the current index
            prod[i] *= arr[j];
}
```

The resulting product array is `prod[]`.

Comment: David, while your code works, this is a `O(n²)` algorithm, OP algorithm is already `O(n)`, there are `O(n)` algorithms available (like the ones that I linked as duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

Typically for this question, does not count the answers with division, it has to be an efficient algorithm in terms of time and space.

look at below which produce O(n) time & O(n) space

```
public int[] otherIndexProduct(int array[]) {

    int results[] = new int[array.length];

    results[0] = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {

        results[i + 1] = results[i] * array[i];
    }

    int before = 1;

    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        results[i] *= before;
        before *= array[i];
    }

    return results;
}
```

there is an interesting another way of getting there with recursion and it update the input array as well without using another array

```
public int product(int array[], int post, int index) {

    int prev = 1;

    if (index < array.length) {

        prev = product(array, post * array[index], index + 1);
        int current = array[index];
        array[index] = post * prev;
        prev *= current;
    }

    return prev;
}
```